# spring mvc display AJAX call returned data on same web page rather separate web page

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to play with simple web app using spring boot and ajax.
my idea is to when i am submit Http POST form data, i want call the controller via AJAX call and display the result on the same web page.

When i run the sprint boot App it picks up correct page index.html on http://localhost:8080/.

currently i can make ajax call , but problem is page is forwarding to http://localhost:8080/test  displays

> "Greetings from Spring Boot! @myemail"

, but i want it display this and remain in the same page with just data being returned from the controller.

definitely i am missing some thing fundamentally wrong. following are my code snippets.

**index.html:**

```
<form id="signup-form" method=post action="/test">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address"/><input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

**Ajax call:**

```
$form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {

                    var data = 'dmc='+ encodeURIComponent(dmc.value);
                        $.ajax({
                            url:"test",
                            data : data,
                            type : "POST",

                            success : function(response) {
                                alert( response );
                                $message._show('success', response);
                            },
                            error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                                alert(xhr.responseText);
                        },
                            complete: function() {
                                window.location = 'index.html';
                              }

                        });
                        return false;

                });
```

**Rest Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String index(@RequestParam(value="email", required=false) String email) {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot! "+email+";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this existing question:

[How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Try removing the 'type="submit"' property from your button and giving your button an id.

```
<input id="buttonId" value="Sign Up" />
```

Then, use $('buttonId').on('click', function()), where 'buttonId' is the new id you have assigned to the button, instead:

```
$('buttonId').on('click', function() {

                var data = 'dmc='+ encodeURIComponent(dmc.value);
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"test",
                        data : data,
                        type : "POST",

                        success : function(response) {
                            alert( response );
                            $message._show('success', response);
                        },
                        error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                    },
                        complete: function() {
                            window.location = 'index.html';
                          }

                    });
            });
```

You shouldn't need to return false in  your js function. Your controller looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would use ResponseBody:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String index(@RequestParam(value="email", required=false) String email)
```

And then:

```
success : function(response) {
    $message._show('success', response);
 },
```

Comment: i am not using ResponseBody, as i am using Annotation RestController on my class where you don't need to declare.

Comment: What is your success, complete, and error methods doing now?  Any output?

Comment: You said you want to remain on the same page, but you're changing locations:  window.location = 'index.html';